# Two pygame windows running alongside each other

Tags: input, pygame, python-3.3

I am using eztext to gather input for my program, but the input window is preventing the output window from being opened(I can't see the display until the input window is closed)

Any help on the problem described above is much appreciated, after a long trawl through the internet I can't seem to find any solutions that I can modify to suit my purposes, though if anyone sees anything I've missed, I would be grateful for a link.

Thanks again in advance

A.J.P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using 2 threads: one for the first window and a second for the other. Like this, both window will open.
edit:
For example, these two threads will communicate with a list. But i's better to use classes:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

informations = []

def funct_a (informations):
    while (1):
        sleep (0.5)
        print informations

def funct_b (informations):
    a = 0
    while (1):
        sleep (1)
        informations.append (a)
        a += 1

Thread (target = funct_a, args = (informations, )).start ()
Thread (target = funct_b, args = (informations, )).start ()
```